# Многотабличные запросы. Выборка двух строк из одной таблицы с одинаковым значением в одном из стобцов

Tags: sql, sql-server

БД содержит следующие траблицы: films, persons и creators. Creators имеет два внешних ключа к films и persons, а также поля "Характер участия" (Режиссёрт, Актёр, Композитор и т.д) and "Роль". Я хочу вывести список фильмов, режиссёр которых также играет главную роль в фильме с указанием его фамилии и роли.

```
create table films (
film_id tinyint identity(1, 1),
film_name varchar(20) not null,
film_studio varchar(25) not null,
film_year int not null,
film_country varchar(20) null,
film_length tinyint not null,
film_genre varchar(15) not null,
constraint PK_films primary key(film_id),
);

create table persons (
person_id tinyint identity(1, 1),
person_name varchar(50) not null,
person_bday date not null,
person_dday date,
constraint PK_persons primary key(person_id),
);

create table creators (
creator_id tinyint identity(1, 1),
creator_film tinyint not null,
creator_person tinyint not null,
creator_who varchar(20) not null,
creator_role varchar(20),
constraint PK_creators primary key(creator_id),
constraint FK_CF foreign key(creator_film) references films(film_id),
constraint FK_CP foreign key(creator_person) references persons(person_id),
constraint CH_Who check(creator_who='director' or creator_who='actor' or creator_who='composer'),
);

insert into films(film_name, film_studio, film_year, film_country, film_length, film_genre) values ('Film1', 'Studio1', 2018, 'USA', 100, 'Genre1')
insert into films(film_name, film_studio, film_year, film_country, film_length, film_genre) values ('Film2', 'Studio2', 2018, 'USA', 120, 'Genre2')
insert into films(film_name, film_studio, film_year, film_country, film_length, film_genre) values ('Film3', 'Studio3', 2000, 'England', 90, 'Genre3')

insert into persons(person_name, person_bday, person_dday) values ('John Smitt', '1988-12-12', null)
insert into persons(person_name, person_bday, person_dday) values ('Mel Gibson
', '1988-12-12', null)
insert into persons(person_name, person_bday, person_dday) values ('Miley Cyrus', '2001-12-12', null)
insert into persons(person_name, person_bday, person_dday) values ('Deadpool', '1999-12-12', null)

insert into creators(creator_film, creator_person, creator_who) values (1, 1, 'Director')
insert into creators(creator_film, creator_person, creator_who, creator_role) values (1, 1, 'Actor', 'Main')
insert into creators(creator_film, creator_person, creator_who, creator_role) values (2, 3, 'Actor', 'Secondary')
insert into creators(creator_film, creator_person, creator_who, creator_role) values (3, 4, 'Actor', 'Secondary')
```

Ожидаемый вывод: Film1 John Smith Main

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
films.film_name,
persons.person_name,
actor.creator_role
FROM creators director
INNER JOIN creators actor
ON director.creator_person = actor.creator_person
   AND actor.creator_who = 'Актёр'
LEFT JOIN films
ON director.creator_film = films.film_id
LEFT JOIN persons
ON director.creator_person = persons.person_id
WHERE director.creator_who = 'Режисcёр'
```

Comment: Запрос неверный. То, что он даёт правильный результат на некоем наборе данных - случайность.

Comment: @Akina какой будет правильным?